# Obtaining the sum of only the latest Elasticsearch docs, aggregated/grouped by some field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement to calculate the sum of fields in documents, grouped by some other field, but only the entries for which some third field is the latest.

for example, for these docs:

```
{
    "time": "2019-08-21T13:00:00",
    "session_id": "1",
    "byte_count": 200,
    "ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
{
    "time": "2019-08-21T12:00:00",
    "session_id": "1",
    "byte_count": 100,
    "ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
{
    "time": "2019-08-21T12:00:00",
    "session_id": "2",
    "byte_count": 123,
    "ip": "2.2.2.2"
}
{
    "time": "2019-08-21T14:00:00",
    "session_id": "3",
    "byte_count": 100,
    "ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
```

need to be grouped by `session_id`, but only have the latest entry, and those results must be grouped by `ip`, and summed on `byte_count`

I have seen one can do grouping with `collapse`, and it works. I’ve also seen one can do sum with aggregation (`aggs`), but when I use the two together, it looks like the `aggs` operates on the actual docs, not the result of the `collapse`. This search

```
{
    "collapse": {
        "field": "session_id",
        "inner_hits": {
            "name": "most_recent",
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
                {
                    "time": "desc"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_ip": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "ip"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "total_bytes": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "byte_count"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has the correct three hits, but the aggregation output has these buckets:

```
buckets": [
    {
        "key": "1.1.1.1",
        "doc_count": 3,
        "total_bytes": {
            "value": 400
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "2.2.2.2",
        "doc_count": 1,
        "total_bytes": {
            "value": 123
        }
    }
]
```

I’ve also seen one can group with `aggs` `top_hits`, but when I try to do an `aggs` `sum` on the result as such:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "by_session": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "session_id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "per_session": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "time": "desc"
                            }
                        ],
                        "size": 1
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "per_ip": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "ip"
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "total_bytes": {
                                    "sum": {
                                        "field": "byte_count"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get error:

`Aggregator [per_session] of type [top_hits] cannot accept sub-aggregations`

How can I update the search params to have the expected result of:

```
{
    "key": "1.1.1.1",
    "doc_count": 2,
    "total_bytes": {
        "value": 300
    }
},
{
    "key": "2.2.2.2",
    "doc_count": 1,
    "total_bytes": {
        "value": 123
    }
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test data used:

```
PUT test
POST test/_doc
{
    "time": "2019-08-21T13:00:00",
    "session_id": 1,
    "byte_count": 200,
    "ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
POST test/_doc
{
    "time": "2019-08-21T13:00:00",
    "session_id": 1,
    "byte_count": 700,
    "ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
POST test/_doc
{
    "time": "2019-08-21T12:00:00",
    "session_id": 1,
    "byte_count": 100,
    "ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
POST test/_doc
{
    "time": "2019-08-21T12:00:00",
    "session_id": 2,
    "byte_count": 123,
    "ip": "2.2.2.2"
}
POST test/_doc
{
    "time": "2019-08-21T14:00:00",
    "session_id": 3,
    "byte_count": 100,
    "ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
```

I am not sure if I understand correctly. You said "the latest entry":
"need to be grouped by session_id, but only **have the latest entry**, and those results must be grouped by ip, and summed on byte_count"

Does this mean the latest "time"?
From your input data don't you expect to get for "ip": "1.1.1.1" the following result?:

```
{
"time": "2019-08-21T14:00:00",
"session_id": "3",
"byte_count": 100,
"ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
```

Because this has a newer "time" compared with the other documents with ip:1.1.1.1?

Anyway here is a query that groups by IP and then groups by session_id. The seesion id buckets are then sorted by the newest "time"

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "per_ip": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "ip"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "per_Session": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "session_id",
                             "order" : { "my_max_date" : "desc" }

                        },
                        "aggs": {
                            "total_bytes": {
                                "sum": {
                                    "field": "byte_count"
                                }
                            },
                            "my_max_date" : { "max" : { "field" : "time" } }
                        }

                    }
        }
    }
}
}
```

If you want to get just the first bucket , just add "size":1 after the order.
Then you need to extract the documents from your aggregations.

This is what I got:

```
 "per_ip" : {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "1.1.1.1",
      "doc_count" : 3,
      "per_Session" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : 3,
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "total_bytes" : {
              "value" : 100.0
            },
            "my_max_date" : {
              "value" : 1.566396E12,
              "value_as_string" : "2019-08-21T14:00:00.000Z"
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : 1,
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "total_bytes" : {
              "value" : 300.0
            },
            "my_max_date" : {
              "value" : 1.5663924E12,
              "value_as_string" : "2019-08-21T13:00:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key" : "2.2.2.2",
      "doc_count" : 1,
      "per_Session" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : 2,
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "total_bytes" : {
              "value" : 123.0
            },
            "my_max_date" : {
              "value" : 1.5663888E12,
              "value_as_string" : "2019-08-21T12:00:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
```

UPDATE:

After first 2 comment discussion added following query which adds "time" field aggregation buckets to the session_id buckets. This allows selecting the newest entry. This still needs to groups the results, but this can maybe be done on the client side by reading the buckets and doing a sum or maybe it can be possible with ["Sum Bucket Aggregation"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html)

```
{
"size": 5,
"aggs": {
    "per_ip": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "ip"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "per_Session": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "session_id"
                        },
                        "aggs": {

                            "my_max_date" : { 
                                "terms": {
                                  "field": "time",
                                  "order": [
                                    {
                                      "_key": "desc"
                                    }
                                  ],
                                  "size":1
                              },
                              "aggs" :
                              {
                                 "total_bytes": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "byte_count",
                                        "size":2
                                    }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                        }

                    }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer andreyro. Yes, by "latest" entry, I mean for all the entries with the same `session_id`, I am only interested in the one with the highest value for `time`. You will see there are three sessions, they have `session_id` 1,2 and 3 respectively. `session_id` 2 belongs to ip 2.2.2.2, while `session_id` 1 and 3 belong to 1.1.1.1. There are two entries with `session_id` 1, I'm only interested in the 13:00 one, as it is the latest. So my end result for 1.1.1.1 needs to be 200+100 = 300, and for 2.2.2.2 the sum of the one entry which is 123.

Comment: The problem with your result, is in `"key" : "1.1.1.1"`, `"key" : 1,` has a value of 300, which is the sum of all the values for `session_id=1`. I only need the value for `"13:00:00"`, ie 200, which is the latest for `session_id=1`. And then I need to sum together all *those* values for 1.1.1.1, to reach the sum of the `"13:00:00"` and `"14:00:00"` values, ie 200 + 100 = 300

Comment: @Vuade Clearer now. I was confused by the fact that the entry that was not needed ("12:00") had the same value =100 as the other one ("14:00"). I edited response with another query, but it s not exactly what you need, but maybe it helps you (if you did not fix this already)
The query creates buckets with just the data you need, but does not sum the results. you can do it either on the client side, or maybe you can try to see if it works with the sum buckets (see link from response)

Comment: @ andreyro thanks a lot, really appreciate it. Your proposed aggregation structure hat the exact results I required, and I was able to sum them with `sum_bucket`. Just had to add intermediately `sum_bucket`, because `buckets_path` can't go three levels deep, only two